# Why is AutoScroll redirecting to previous page

Tags: php, jquery, html, autoscroll

I have a problem with a function I just created. I'm trying to autoscroll to a specific user on a table. When I select my button it scrolls to the user, but then it reloads the previous page.

You would go to xxx.com and then select a menu that takes to xxx.com/results_page.php. From here you will select another link that takes you to xxx.com/results.php. From here you will select the Autoscroll button. The button takes you to the correct spot on the page and then reloads to, xxx.com/results_page.php.

I copied this script from a friend, so Im not quite sure how it is working. 
This is my button, I have it disabled currently since it is broke.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan=2>
        <button onclick="findUser()" title="Sorry, I'm still working  on this." disabled>My Entry</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the function at the top of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findUser(){
    $(window).scrollTop($("td:contains('<?php echo $_SESSION['loggedInUser']; ?>'):last").offset().top);
}
</script>
```

Let me know what else I can give to help here.  I can setup a test page if need be.

Testing page 
Testing.daqspickem.com
Login: Guest 
Pass:  Guest

After logging in, go to testing.daqspickem.com/results.php. The button is on that page. 
[The results page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdGiJ.png)
[The results pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cYR1.png)

This code is where I set the TD that I want to find.

```
    switch ($user_names_display)
    {
            case 1:
                    echo '      <td>' . trim($tmpUser->firstname . ' ' . $tmpUser->lastname) . '</td>' . "\n";
                    break;
            case 2:
                    echo '  <td><img src="images/logos/' . trim($tmpUser->template_name) . '.gif" style="opacity: .8; width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-left: 0px; z-index: -1;" />' . trim($tmpUser->userName) . '</td>' . "\n";
                    break;
            default: //3
                    echo ' <td><img src="images/logos/' . trim($tmpUser->template_name) . '.svg" style="width="15px" height="15px" /><abbrev title="' . trim($tmpUser->userName) . '&#10;' . trim($tmpUser->firstname . ' ' . $tmpUser->lastname) . '">' . substr($tmpUser->userName, 0, 17) . '</abbrev>
</td>' . "\n";
                    break;
    }
```

Comment: That test page would definitely be needed. The purpose of your scrip is not clear enough. You can also set up a js fiddle. Thanks

Comment: I told you the purpose in the description. I'm trying to auto scroll to a specific user("td:contains('<?php echo $_SESSION['loggedInUser']; ?>'):last") on a table.    I want to click on the button and scroll through the table to that record.

Comment: Edited original post with test page.

Comment: I think I just need to figure out how to prevent the page refresh. I got off down a rabbit hole, but the script works besides the refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findUser(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).scrollTop($("td:contains('<?php echo $_SESSION['loggedInUser']; ?>'):last").offset().top);
}
```

This works because it prevents the `href` from executing it's default functionality.

Comment: Same problem, although I might have found the issue. When I looked at my table it shows user name instead off First:Last, so it might not be finding the record. Would that cause it to reload?

Answer (score 0):

I Guess the issue is with this script,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findUser(){
    $(window).scrollTop($("td:contains('<?php echo $_SESSION['loggedInUser']; ?>'):last").offset().top);
}
</script>
```

Here, your `$_SESSION['loggedInUser']` contains `"Guest"` while the `td` you are referring to has inner HTML `"guest"`

That change would fix it, but you will need to design a fall back to handle such situations where the user is not present in the table.

Comment: You lost me here, you just posted the same code I started with?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I added a Form around my button and it seems to have fixed the issue. I would be open for any other ideas though, since that doesnt seem Ideal. It seems Chrome is the issue with the refresh.

```
      <form id="frmData" onsubmit="return false"> 
  <tr><td colspan = 2 > <button onclick="findUser()" title="Sorry, I'm still working  on this." >My Entry</button></td> </tr></table>
</form>
```

script

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
function findUser()
{
$(window).scrollTop($("td:contains('<?php echo $_SESSION['loggedInUser']; ?>'):last").offset().top);

}
</script>
```